# Open another Java application from existing Java program

Tags: java, swing

I'm building a Java tutorial where there is a button when clicked, opens a notepad application which I built. However how do I go about opening the notepad application in the `ActionListener`? Should I use `ProcessBuilder`?

Comment: Are you wanting to have the other other app in a separate process, if not simply instantiate the Class

Comment: Instantiate like NotepadApp newApp = new NotepadApp(); in your listener

Comment: @SaiYeYanNaingAye *"Instantiate like NotepadApp newApp = new NotepadApp(); in your listener"* I agree this is the best approach. Avoid starting a new process unless it is actually necessary. Doing it this way, 'launcher' app. can more easily communicate with or monitor the launched app. Just make sure to `launcherFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE)` as opposed to `EXIT_ON_CLOSE` on the note pad app. - the latter will not only close the note pad, but also kille the JRE and the launcher app.!

Comment: *"notepad application which I built"* - is it a Jar file? Is it contained within the current application's classpath?

Answer (score 0):

If your separate program is a compiled .jar file, use the following code to launch it, but note you will not have any control over it.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar 'path/to/file.jar'");
```

Note this method returns a `Process` object, which you can then modify to your individual needs.

Comment: Given the 'not have any control over it' is a definite hint that instntiating the note pad directly in the running JVM is the way to go (see comments above). See also [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) for many good tips on creating and handling a process correctly.  Then ignore it refers to `exec` and use a `ProcessBuilder` (as the OP alluded to) to create the process. Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for things like paths containing space characters.